# Terminal hangs when title includes unreachable NFS path

Tags: macos, terminal, bash, automount

[Edit: reframing to make the question more clear]

I use the Mac Terminal to access remote linux systems. On the Mac, the bash prompt is set by:

```
PROMPT_COMMAND='echo -ne "\033]0;${USER}@${HOSTNAME}\007"
```

On the *remote*  LINUX system, the bash prompt is set to:

```
 PROMPT_COMMAND='printf "\033]0;%s@%s:%s\007" "${USER}" "${HOSTNAME%%.*}" "${PWD/#$HOME/~}"'
```

(This path is set in the /etc/bashrc on the remote linux system, and is not editable by mere morals)

So, when I start a terminal, the title of my Terminal session looks like:

```
user@mymac -- -bash
```

(the "-- -bash" element appears to be added by Terminal)

And after i ssh to a linux system the title changes to:

```
otheruser@linuxbox:~ -- ssh linuxbox
```

(the "-- ssh linuxbox" element added by Terminal)

The problem is when I switch to an automount path on the REMOTE LINUX system like 'cd /net/hostname/path'  where the NFS path is exported to the Linux system but NOT my Mac,  terminal locks up.  Every window, every tab becomes unusable.

The title at this point has been set to:

```
 otheruser@linuxbox:/net/hostname/path -- ssh linuxbox
```

I finally figured out that my Mac is trying to mount the file nfs file system referenced on the remote terminal session, which I believe is triggered by the title, since that's the only way place the '/net/... path is being passed, and the following mount command are running on my local Mac:

```
 $ ps -ef | grep automount    0   858     1   0 10:58AM ??         0:00.08 automountd
0  1003   858   0 11:03AM ??         0:00.00 /sbin/mount -o nobrowse -t nfs -o retrycnt=0 -o nosuid,nodev -o nosuid -o automounted -o nosuid hostname:/path   /net/hostname/path
0  1004  1003   0 11:03AM ??         0:00.01 /sbin/mount_nfs -o nobrowse -o retrycnt=0 -o nosuid -o nodev -o nosuid -o automounted -o nosuid hostname:/path /net/hostname/path
```

If I 'kill -9' the 'mount_nfs' command, terminal starts responding again until the title of the terminal is changed when the prompt updates.  Which is frequently.

Why is terminal triggering a mount command locally in this case?   How can I stop it?   That is without having to change the prompt on the remote system.

Comment: Why do you expect OS X tp know that the path you give to cd does not exist - it is a valid name

Comment: To put it another way:  why does OS X need to even think about (i.e. try to mount) a remote filesystem based on the title of a Terminal session?  ...especially when that terminal session is to a remote system.

Comment: Like all Unices when you ask for pwd Unix expects the directory to be present and if not it helpfully tries to mount it

Comment: Mark-  the 'pwd' is being executed on the remote system to build the prompt (and title).   Not understanding why OS X cares, and tries to mount the path as well.

Comment: No pwd is always excited in the current system - you would need to exec to execute on any freight system

Comment: I'm logged into a remote system via 'ssh user@remotehost'. It does not make sense to me that the 'pwd' command in the prompt (on the remote host) is executed locally.   After re-reading my original question, I can see how this was not made totally clear.   Does that help?

Comment: I think you need to explain in detail in the question what you are doing and which system the files are on and what prompt each system uses as it is totally unclear

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30874/discussion-between-ray-and-mark).